# C understanding valgrind, stack smashing error

Tags: c, stack-overflow, valgrind

I made a program that sometime it throws a stack smashing detected error. 
It works 99% of the time, but with certain files it throws the error. 
I used valgrind to try identify the error, but i am having trouble understanding the log file.
So here it is:

```
==3797== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3797== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3797== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3797== Command: ./pargrep de nuevo.txt
==3797== Parent PID: 2367
==3797== 
==3797== 
==3797== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3797==     in use at exit: 33,339 bytes in 5 blocks
==3797==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 7 frees, 35,025 bytes allocated
==3797== 
==3797== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 5
==3797==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3797==    by 0x8048FDB: maestro (padre.c:39)
==3797==    by 0x8048ABF: main (main.c:62)
==3797== 
==3797== 55 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 5
==3797==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3797==    by 0x40B878B: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:138)
==3797==    by 0x413D09F: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:32)
==3797==    by 0x413D049: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:29)
==3797==    by 0x8049665: contar_palabra (funcion.c:51)
==3797==    by 0x80494C5: hilos_hijos (hilos.c:90)
==3797==    by 0x4041E98: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
==3797==    by 0x41279ED: clone (clone.S:130)
==3797== 
==3797== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 5
==3797==    at 0x4025315: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==3797==    by 0x4010CD7: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:300)
==3797==    by 0x401146B: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:464)
==3797==    by 0x40425C6: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (allocatestack.c:570)
==3797==    by 0x80490E1: maestro (padre.c:84)
==3797==    by 0x8048ABF: main (main.c:62)
==3797== 
==3797== 352 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 5
==3797==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3797==    by 0x40B3537: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==3797==    by 0x40B360B: fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 (iofopen.c:107)
==3797==    by 0x804907D: maestro (padre.c:66)
==3797==    by 0x8048ABF: main (main.c:62)
==3797== 
==3797== 32,792 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 5
==3797==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3797==    by 0x40EBA18: __alloc_dir (opendir.c:186)
==3797==    by 0x40EBB49: opendir (opendir.c:141)
==3797==    by 0x8049013: maestro (padre.c:53)
==3797==    by 0x8048ABF: main (main.c:62)
==3797== 
==3797== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3797==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3797==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3797==      possibly lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==3797==    still reachable: 33,203 bytes in 4 blocks
==3797==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3797== 
==3797== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3797== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 8)
```

i really dont understand whats the error.I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8):

you need to differ between stack smashing and heap memory errors.

Valgrind is telling you that some memory has not been freed and some is possibly lost. but that might have nothing to do with your real problem: the stack smashing.

stack means: local variables (often char arrays), any other arrays which are not allocated etc.

heap: anything that has been alloced with malloc, calloc, realloc etc.

So if you get a stack smashing, chances are high, that you somewhere write over the end of an array.
check strcpy, memcpy, and array access first (where you write to a memory which was not allocated).

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between automatic and dynamic storage duration errors

Answer (score 2):

With Valgrind 3.7.0, you might try the experimental tool exp-sgcheck
which finds stack and global overruns.
As indicated, this is an experimental tool, so might not be as high quality
as memcheck and other non experimental Valgrind tools.
(e.g. might give false positive and/or false negative).
exp-sgcheck however helped me once to find a nasty array overrun bug.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind does not detect [array overruns](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.overruns), which could be the cause of your observed stack smashing.

Answer (score 0):

With those messages Valgrind is telling you that memory has been allocated (and showing you a stack trace of how the call to malloc came about) but that memory from those allocations have never been freed.

More information can be found at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks

Comment: ok ok i understand what you are saying. i checked the lines of the "still reachable" error and those lines are where i assign a global variable a value. the possibly lost is when i create a number of threads. and the record 2, that line is the end of a function. So really i have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: still reachable means the program is still holding a pointer to the memory that was allocated. possibly lost means valgrind thinks you probably cleared a pointer to the memory allocation, but never freed the memory. these memory leaks might not have anything to do with your other issues, since malloc is about heap memory, not the stack. and in some cases, freeing heap allocations is not a worthwhile exercise, since they'll all be freed when the program exits.